# react-native-image-picker iOS image not save

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In iOS, everything is fine except image not save. Camera capture and retrieve url to image component all fine. But when I check back to photo / gallery , captured photo are not there.

Options that I use :

```
var optionsIOS = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  cancelButtonTitle:'Cancel',
  takePhotoButtonTitle:'Photo Capture',
  chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle:'Choose from Gallery',
  quality:0.5,
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, you need to set `cameraRoll` props to true like this:

```
var optionsIOS = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  cancelButtonTitle:'Cancel',
  takePhotoButtonTitle:'Photo Capture',
  chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle:'Choose from Gallery',
  quality:0.5,
  storageOptions: {
    cameraRoll: true,
    skipBackup: true
  }
};
```

You can all the different props [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md).

Answer (score 0):

Code below is what I use in my RN App to save an image.

```
saveToCameraRoll = (image) => {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    fileCache : true,
    appendExt : 'jpg'
  })
  .fetch('GET', image.urls.small)
  .then((res) => {
    CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path())
      .then(Alert.alert('Success', 'Photo added to camera roll!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('err:', err))
  })
} else {
  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(image.urls.small)
    .then(Alert.alert('Success', 'Photo added to camera roll!'))
}
}
```

Comment: but im using react-native-image-picker

Comment: @ImHappy Try adding storageOptions.cameraRoll: true